# is this a cover or what is this referring to?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, notation

$X = C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$, $T = T(d_\infty)$. where $(X,T)$ is a topological space could some one please explain what $X=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ means, my teacher never explained ? Is it some kind of cover ?

Comment: It could be a good thing to read an introductory topology book, in my opinion

Answer (score 5):

$C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

It's just the collection of all continuous mappings from $[0, 1]$ to $\Bbb R$ (with respect to the usual topology of $[0, 1]$ inherited from $\Bbb R$), endowed with the topology given by the uniform norm $||•||_{\infty}$.

Let me know if you don't understand anything.